# How to return 0 or 1 to check available number in a range in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure where i want to check available number in a range. The stored procedure will return 0 or 1 as bit.

Case 0 means, the number is not available

Case 1 means, the number is available.

I have written this query

```
Declare @recivedNo As INT = 82 
    Declare @minSourceNo as INT
    Declare @maxSourceNo as INT

    Select @minSourceNo =  min(Source_no) from Source 
    Select @maxSourceNo =  max(Source_no) from Source 

    IF(Select COunt(1) from Source
    WHere Source_no = @recivedNo AND @recivedNo Between @minSourceNo AND @maxSourceNo

    )>0
    begin 
    Select 0 as is_valid
    end
    else
    Select 1 as is_valid
```

Suppose the min number is 1 and max is 88. And available number is 5.
If i check number 10. It reruns 0 which is correct. If i check number 5 it returns 1 which is fine. Note the both number 5 and 10 are within the range. But if i check number 100. It also returns 1 which is not correct for me. It should return 0 because 100 is not in the range. Is there any way to check this?

Comment: I think you need to interchange select 0 as is_valid and select 1 as is_valid . Also post your data. Although query is quite simple but posting the data would just help validate the facts. Also what is the basis for your claim that return 0 for 10 is correct and returning 1 for 5 is correct. I can assume but assumption is not good. I have replicated your query and is working fine. so there must be some mistake.

Comment: It returns 1 if the number is not in range.

Comment: In that case it should return 1 for both 5 and 10. Also look at @Thorsten Kettner answer or other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your evaluation "in the table and between min and max" is incorrect. You are interested in whether the number is available (i.e. "**not** in the table and between min and max") or not.

```
select case when @recivedNo between @minSourceNo and @maxSourceNo 
            and not exists (select * from source where source_no = @recivedNo)
       then 1 else 0 end as is_valid;
```

Or vice versa:

```
select case when @recivedNo not between @minSourceNo and @maxSourceNo 
            or exists (select * from source where source_no = @recivedNo)
       then 0 else 1 end as is_valid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your if statement is the issue. Try "If exists" as below

```
IF EXISTS (Select count(1) from Source
WHere Source_no = @recivedNo AND (@recivedNo Between @minSourceNo AND @maxSourceNo)

)
BEGIN 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
END
```

You can also use select * inside if exists or select top 1 from source

```
IF EXISTS (Select * from Source
WHere Source_no = @recivedNo AND (@recivedNo Between @minSourceNo AND @maxSourceNo)

)
BEGIN 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
END
```

Comment: It returns 0 in all cases.

Comment: Why has this answer been accepted? It's wrong. The first query is always true (`count(1)` always exists). The second query doesn't work either; 100 is treated as available although it's not in the range.

Comment: Idea was to provide hint that if exists can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `@minSourceNo` and `@maxSourceNo` in one query. And use `between` in case statement:

```
DECLARE @recivedNo As INT = 10,
        @minSourceNo as INT,
        @maxSourceNo as INT

SELECT  @minSourceNo =  min(Source_no),
        @maxSourceNo =  max(Source_no) 
FROM @source

IF (
    SELECT COUNT(*)+CASE WHEN @recivedNo Between @minSourceNo AND @maxSourceNo THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM @source
    WHERE Source_no = @recivedNo 
) != 1 
SELECT 0 as is_valid
ELSE
SELECT 1 as is_valid
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  @minSourceNo,  @maxSourceNo can have arbitrary values

```
-- sample data - params
declare @Source table (sourceNo int);
insert @Source (sourceNo)
values (2),(25),(120);

Declare @minSourceNo as INT = 20;
Declare @maxSourceNo as INT = 50;

-- sample data
Declare @recivedSamples table (recivedNo int);
insert @recivedSamples(recivedNo)
values (2),(25),(30),(120);

-- query
select recivedNo, 
       flag=coalesce((select 1 n 
                 from @Source s
                 where s.sourceNo between @minSourceNo and @maxSourceNo
                  and s.sourceNo = r.recivedNo), 0)
from @recivedSamples r
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting values for the variables `@minSourceNo` and `@maxSourceNo` from the `source` table itself, the query  will return the minimum and maximum value of `SourceNo` from that table. so the condition `@recivedNo Between @minSourceNo AND @maxSourceNo` will always be satisfies unless and until the input `@recivedNo` is not present in the `Source` table.

Anyway,below script will do the same thing,but using `EXIST` .

```
    DECLARE @recivedNo    INT = 82 
    DECLARE @minSourceNo  INT
    DECLARE @maxSourceNo  INT

    SELECT  @minSourceNo =  min(Source_no), @maxSourceNo =  max(Source_no) FROM Source 


    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Source
               WHERE Source_no = @recivedNo AND @recivedNo Between @minSourceNo AND @maxSourceNo)
        BEGIN 
        SELECT 1 AS is_valid
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SELECT 0 AS is_valid
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written this query and it is working fine.

```
Declare @number as INT = 120
Declare @minsourceNo as INT 
Declare @maxsourceNo as INT 

Select @minsourceNo =  min(source_no)  from source 
Select @maxsourceNo =  max(source_no)  from source 

IF EXists(Select * from source where source_no = @number)
Begin
select Cast(0 as bit)
end
else
If(@number between @minsourceNo and @maxsourceNo)
Begin
select Cast(1 as bit)
end
else
select Cast(0 as bit)
```

Comment: Yes, that's a possiblity. I would turn it around, though: 0 when it's outside the range, otherwise look it up in the table, so as to avoid the select on invalid ranges. However, I find my own answer quite straight-forward, so I wonder why you didn't use it, but wrote something else. What is it about my solution that you didn't like?

Comment: Your query always return 0. Whatever number is.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it was my mistake. I just missed a check from your query. I just check it and it is working fine. Your answer is correct. I am sorry for my mistake. You must need mark for right answer.